# Using 3rd party UI component in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, uistoryboard

I'm trying to use a button from third party [library](https://github.com/a1anyip/AYVibrantButton) for my iOS app.

I already put `AYVibrantButton` in my **Podfile**, and used `pod install`. I would expect it to appear somewhere in the identity inspector, but it's nowhere to be found. Searching for `AYVibrantButton` in Xcode's Help search bar doesn't bring up anything either

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: the library's link explain how you should use it. Check if you have imported AYVibrantButton in your UIViewController, and also don't forget that after creating the object, you must do view.addSubview(button)

Comment: Are you opening project or workspace?

Comment: @ParthAdroja I'm opening workspace

Comment: @Daniel is there a way I can use the button through the storyboard, or must it be programmatic? Also, all the code in the library is in objective-c

Comment: @efthimio I'm pretty sure these cocoapods cannot be used from storyboard, just programmatically... about objective-c code, I've already used obj-c pods in swift code just by importing, I think you can try using [Swiftify](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/) if you face problems converting code

Answer (score 0):

because if you check in interface file, AYVibrantButton is subclass of UIControl, to assign it to your button that must be subclass of UIButton.
You can try changing it to UiButton (you may need to unlock the file to make changes, check the license before making changes)